# How can I call angular function when bootstrap modal popup

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using boostrap modal like this:

```
<!--Permission MODAL-->
<div class="modal fade" id="transactionPermissionModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-center">Create New</p>

        <div *ngIf="shouldPermissionsVisible">

          <div *ngFor="let permittedProfile of assignedPermissions" class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <p class="myText float-left">{{permittedProfile.profile.email}}({{permittedProfile.permission_type}})</p>
              <span style="float: right; cursor: pointer" (click)="RemovePermissionToUser(permittedProfile.profile.email)">&times;</span>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7" style="padding-right: 0px;">
            <input type="text" style="border-right: none" class="new-transaction-textfield" placeholder="Invite Someone" id="permission-email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
            <select id="permission-dropdown" style="background-color: transparent; height: 32px; border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;border-left: none; outline: none">
              <option value="edit">can edit</option>
              <option value="view">can view</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2" style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <button type="button" class="btn invite-btn" (click)="GivePermissionToUser()">Invite</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br />

      </div>
      <!--<div class="modal-footer">-->
      <button type="button" id="permission-modal-close-btn" data-dismiss="modal" style="display: none">Close</button>
      <!--</div>-->
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to call a function whenever popup appears on screen. This modal is totally in another component and it is triggered from parent component. Here is the function which I want to call:

```
/**
   * Get permission list from server
   *
   * @param nextLink: link to retrieve a specific page/result_set
   * @param childIndex: index number if user has clicked any child of a transaction otherwise it 'll be null
   */
  public GetPermissionsList(nextLink, childIndex: number = null) {
    if (nextLink === '') {
      this.assignedPermissions = [];
    }

    this.transactionsService.HandlePermissionRequestGeneracially(
      {}, this.url + nextLink, 'GET'
    ).subscribe((response) => {

      for (const entry of response.results) {
        this.assignedPermissions.push(entry);
      }

      this.shouldPermissionsVisible = true;

      this.assignedPermissions = this.assignedPermissions.slice(0);

      const next = response.next;
      if (next !== null) {
        this.GetPermissionsList(next.substring(next.indexOf('?'), next.length), childIndex);
        return;
      }
    }, (error) => {
      this.snackbarHandler.showSnackBar('Error while getting permission');
    });
  }
```

Problem is if I call it via jquery like shown below then it doesn't update data on UI. instead it show it when modal popsup next time.

```
const myThis = this;
$('#transactionPermissionModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      this.GetPermissionsList('');
    });
```

Perhaps its because of `this` instance. I need help about how can I call this function when modal pops-up (I would prefer not using any jquery)

Comment: How are you rendering the modal?  Also where does the GetPermissionsList function live?  On the parent?  Maybe you can make it a service. Can you add code which shows how you are firing the modal?

Comment: what if u call it from the component that opens the modal, on button click for example.

Comment: Have you considered using ngx-bootstrap or ng-bootstrap instead, which is meant for angular, makes your life so much easier...

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function from the same spot you call the modal from. 
If the modal is called when the user tries an action, that action should trigger the modal and the function.

If the modal happens as soon as the page loads, then in the ngOnInit function associated with that page should trigger the function.

Once you call the function, for whatever information needs changing, you would still need to have the function called change the contents of the modal for the already rendered content to change.

There are multiple ways to change rendered content, the method would depend on your current setup. From inside the component associated with the page you can use Angular's default life cycle hooks, among other options. You can find the list of hooks and when to use them here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks